# Why does UIImageView load JPEGs faster than PNGs?

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, png, jpeg

I've realized that `UIImageView` loads JPEG images faster than PNG files. Or, at least it renders images faster, for example using its `startAnimating` method.
1. How fast jpg files loaded than png files.
2. And my main question is, Why? Does PNG images have complex structure?!
I have tested this with a collection of JPEGs and another collection of PNGs. Almost all have the same file size.

Comment: Also take the file size into account. PNG files may be heavier than compressed JPEG ones, for the same dimensions.

Comment: @Macmade JPG and PNG files have almost same size

Comment: Does your PNG have an alpha (transparency) component?  That might make it slower.  JPEGs never have alpha.  You can check by opening the PNG in Preview, choosing Tools > Show Inspector, going to the More Info tab of the inspector, and the General tab under that.  If "Has Alpha" is 1, it has an alpha component.